# Наклонение глагола "сходил бы"

Tags: глаголы, наклонение, сослагательное

> Сходил бы ты на реку, Петя, воды принес.

Сходил бы — это глагол в повелительном или в сослагательном наклонении?
Всегда ли частица "бы" указывает на сослагательное наклонение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Сходил бы ты на реку, Петя, воды принес.**

Это форма сослагательного наклонения глагола (***сходил бы***) в значении повелительного наклонения.

Из книги Розенталя "Современный русский язык":

Сослагательное наклонение может употребляться в значении повелительного наклонения, когда высказывается **мягкий совет, просьба или желание:** ***Помирилась бы  ты с ним*.**

2)  Область применения частицы БЫ и ее значения указаны  в толковом словаре. Частица БЫ употребляется **с глаг. в прош. вр., с инф. или с предикат. нареч.**

Как известно, **форма сослагательного наклонения  — это глагол в прошедшем времени + частица БЫ.**

Из этого следует, что БЫ используется не только для образования сослагательного наклонения, например: Поохотиться бы по-настоящему! Как бы не опоздать.